# Updating a MYSQL table with multiple if statements

Tags: mysql, database

Having some trouble getting this MYSQL code to work. I was attempting to add an onUpdate trigger via PHPMYAdmin, that takes the row, then takes the modified entry and checks to see if it is greater than some values below. 
What I was trying to do was have the code check one if statement,execute the code inside the if, and then go to the next if statement after that.I looked around but couldn't figure out where I went wrong. Help is appreciated!

The code:

```
IF NEW.someVal> 10 THEN
UPDATE someTable 
SET someTable.colA = someTable.colA +1;
END IF;

IF NEW.someVal > 50 THEN
UPDATE someTable 
SET someTable.colB = someTable.colB +1;
END IF;

IF NEW.someVal > 100 THEN
UPDATE someTable 
SET someTable.colC = someTable.colC +1;
END IF;
```

The error: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL          server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF NEW.someVal > 10 THEN 
UPDATE someTable.co'... at line 6

If I were to take any of these if statements, and only use on of them in the trigger I'm trying to create, the trigger works fine.

Comment: What is `IF NEW.someVal> 10 THEN`? `UPDATE` statements don't accept such code construct.

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Updated my post with the error I'm getting

Comment: The table `someTable` is the same that you create the trigger for?

Comment: table sometable is a different table

Comment: Does some other statement precede those?
Also, did you follow the examples here? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html

Comment: No statement precedes this. I'm using the PHPMyAdmin trigger creator. I believe my syntax should work in accordance to the document, although I've never seen any examples that demonstrate multiple if statements in the same trigger that aren't nested.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the same functionality without using the IF condition, as follows:

```
UPDATE someTable 
SET someTable.colA = someTable.colA +1
WHERE someTable.colA +1 > 10;

UPDATE someTable 
SET someTable.colB = someTable.colB +1
WHERE someTable.colB +1 > 50;

UPDATE someTable 
SET someTable.colC = someTable.colC +1
WHERE someTable.colC +1 > 100;
```